# ibus-ui-gtk3 hangul keyboard layout property panel window won't go away

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 on amd64.

When I installed a Korean keyboard layout ("input method") through IBus, a small window appeared on my screen.

[image: ibus-ui-gtk3 property panel window]

Using `xwininfo` I found that this window is titled "ibus-ui-gtk3".

The window has options relating to the Korean input method (e.g. a button to toggle between hangul and hanja). However, the window never goes away, even when I switch to a different input method (e.g. English).

How do I make this window go away, or at least only show up when using the Korean input method?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by opening "IBus Preferences" (`ibus-setup` from CLI) and changed the "Show property panel:" option in the "General" tab to "Do not show".

Now the "property panel" (as I now know it is called) is not present. There is also a "Hide automatically" option that seems to make the window only show up when you start typing.

[image: "IBus Preferences" window with the "Show property panel" option set to "Hide automatically"]

Comment: The default value of that setting should be "Do not show". Had you changed it previously?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No, I don't think I changed it manually. The window popped up the first time I switched to the Korean input method. Now that I have had the setting set to "Hide automatically" for a while, it seems that the window pops up whenever I click into some text box (e.g. url bar in firefox), even with the English input method, so I will probably change it to "Do not show".

Comment: I see. Good that you figured out the applicable setting anyway.